# How would I implement an icon library (Tabler) in Vuetify?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, icons, vuetify.js, node-modules

I am using Vue2 and Vuetify in a project. I would like to be able to use any icon from the Tabler icon library, like so:

```js
<v-icon>custom-icon-name</v-icon
```

I do not want to use the custom component based system with:

```js
<v-icon>$vuetify.icons.iconName</v-icons>
```

Conceptually, what would be some possible solutions? Will I need to create a module for this, and if so, what would be a good approach? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option that technically is working for me—but will be tedious to do—is to implement a TablerIcon.vue component:

```
    <template>
    <div>
        <template v-if="iconName=='Deg360ViewIcon'">
            <Deg360ViewIcon :size="size" :stroke-width="strokewidth" />
        </template>
        <template v-else>
            <QuestionMarkIcon :size="size" :stroke-width="strokewidth" />
        </template>
    </div>
</template>
  
  <style>
  </style>
  
  <script>
  export default {
    name: 'TablerIcon',
    props: ['iconName','size','strokewidth'],
    data() {
      return {
      }
    },
  }
  </script>
```

And then I call this with:

```
import TablerIcon from './TablerIcon.vue'
...
  components: {TablerIcon},

<TablerIcon :iconName="'Deg360ViewIcon'" :size="24" :strokewidth="1.5"/>
```

This seems to be working with the npm package found here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-tabler-icons

Comment: The package you are describing is for Vue 3. I am sorry I forgot to take down this post, we found a solution. However, your approach would be a good solution if you are only using a few of the icons and are concerned with the inability to tree-shake tabler. If you are not worried about tree-shaking and are going to be using a lot of the library's icons, I would just use a global import instead.

import VueTablerIcons from "vue-tabler-icons";
const app = createApp({
...your app setup
});
app.use(VueTablerIcons).mount("#app");

Then in template:

<template>
  <x-icon />
</template>